# Need to understand a Javascript Function

Tags: javascript

I am Python programmer and know least about Javascript.

Can someone please explain what this function (test) means in javascript?

Thank you

```
function test(var1)

{

    var var_str=""+Challenge;

    var var_arr=var_str.split("");

    var LastDig=var_arr.reverse()[0];

    var minDig=var_arr.sort()[0];



    answer=answer+subvar2;

    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Explain what exactly?

Comment: What is the value of `Challenge` inside the function? And the argument `var1` passed into the function is never used.

Comment: I need to replicate this in Python. But for that I need to understand what it is doing. So Ideally I need to understand each line :-(

Comment: You should consult Google first. If you have a specific question about a specific problem, then come back later with that question. The question you've written here is akin to asking someone to do your homework.

Comment: This what I could understand. There are 2 initial values as - `Challenge=345331;

ChallengeId=2627006;

` When it does test(ChallengeId) it gives some result

Comment: @Elliot B. May be you are right, sorry for the trouble

Comment: @Keerthi var1 is used `var x=(var1*3+subvar1)*1;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`split` `reverse` `sort`, `Math.pow`, etc are pre defined functions used in JavaScript. Google to learn more about these. More over, if you are good in programming, then these are just math  equations.

You can do a `console.log` or `alert` like `console.log(var_arr);` `alert(var_arr);` after each line and see what result it gives.

Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sn6mhtzL/)

Comment: got it, Thank you. There is a similar module `math` in python as well and with all the same functions. That makes the job easier. Thank you @Keerthi